# Cross application how to Authorization

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, session, authorization

I need solution for below points.
Scenario : 
We have two applications which will be talking to each other.  One is developed using .net framework 4.8 mvc and other one is .net core 3.1 .
1. Some users will login to .net core and Some will  login on .net mvc,, however internally login Api will be on .net mvc app
2. These two application will also talk to each other internally after login. 
3. I don't want to have DB calls per API.

Please suggest a solution. Thank you in advance

Answer (score 1):

APIs which are being called by 2 apps separate them in third api projecs including login api.
Make api secure. Use token authentication. Both apps should keep access token in cookie after login is successful and send token in every request.

Project1
Login Api along with other apis secured with OAuth 2.0 for apis.

Project2. 
.Net Core App

Project 3
.NET mvc app

Refer this for api auth. 
https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/asp-net-mvc-oauth-2-0-rest-web-api-authorization-using-database-first-approach/